# Symfony tutorial is wrong?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I was trying to follow the symfony tutorial at:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#step-1-create-the-route

But at a certain point I've decided to use php instead twig.

so i was trying to work with templates at step 3 and my pages show me this line

```
extend('::base.html.php') ?> Hello escape($name) ?>!
```

not sure if this is an error from the tutorial since they usually choose work with twig or if I did something wrong.
Its like my page isn't recognizing the php when try to extend it.

this is the full code of the page I'm trying to render:

```
<!-- src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/views/Hello/index.html.php -->
<?php $view->extend('::base.html.php') ?>

Hello <?php echo $view->escape($name) ?>!
```

and i run the page at this url http:// localhost:8080/web/app_dev.php/hello/Peter

this is my controller:

```
class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        // return $this->render(
        //    'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig',
        //    array('name' => $name)
        // );

        // render a PHP template instead
         return $this->render(
             'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.php',
             array('name' => $name)
         );
    }
}
```

and my base:

```
!-- app/Resources/views/base.html.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php $view['slots']->output('title', 'Welcome!') ?></title>
        <?php $view['slots']->output('stylesheets') ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('favicon.ico') ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $view['slots']->output('_content') ?>
        <?php $view['slots']->output('javascripts') ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

notice that I'm using /web/ which isn't in the tutorial. Might this be related with the problem? since I'm telling the base model is at :: ? how can I fix this?

Comment: did you add PHP as a templating engine?

Comment: it was not included in the tutorial, besides the hellocontroller code. I search the folders for something to change but didnt found anything

Comment: thanks found it by another tutorial at http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/PHP.html if you submit an answer ill accept it , it was really stupid bug... but this is what happens when you start learning a new framework :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the ["How to use PHP instead of Twig for Templates"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) article in the documentation, you read that you need to register PHP as a templating engine.

Assuming that you use Yaml as a configuration format:

```yaml
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```